# Not working .docx conversion to blob in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I saving a files( .txt, .docx, .pdf) in a database  using varbinary(MAX) datatype successfully.

Now i am using below code for downloading files from a database. 
I am able to download .txt extension file without any problem.
 **When i tried to download .docx extenstion file  not working as expected. the data is coming as junk characters and word document not able to open *"because we found a problem with its content"*.**

```
$http(request).success(function (d, status, headers) {
    head = headers();

    var contentType = head['content-type'];

    var contentdisposition = head['content-disposition'];
    var fileName = contentdisposition.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
    fileName = fileName.replace(/"/g, '');
    console.log('calling');
    var contentType = head['content-type'];

    var data = d;

    var file = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
    saveAs(file, fileName);
})
.error(function () {

});
```

Comment: need to set dataType in request config...see docs

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, Can you please explain how to set dataType in request config?

Comment: it is explained in `$http` docs

Comment: Sorry, No link found, Please post a link.

Comment: you can't find the angular documentation???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for downloading a file.

```
 $http({
                    url : '/api/DownloadfFile/20',
                    method : 'GET',
                    params : {},
                    headers : {
                        'Content-type': undefined,
                    },
                    responseType : 'arraybuffer'
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    head = headers();
                    var contentType = head['content-type'];
                    var contentdisposition = head['content-disposition'];
                    var fileName = contentdisposition.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
                    fileName = fileName.replace(/"/g, '');

                    var file = new Blob([ data ], {
                        type: contentType
                    });


                    saveAs(file, fileName);


                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                });
```

Comment: use the responseType blob instead... or better yet: if possible don't use ajax at all since it already has content-disposition header